# Remapping Pause|Break to grave with udev

Tags: keyboard

I'm having big issues remapping my <kbd>Pause|Break</kbd> key to grave <kbd>`</kbd>, on Debian 11.

I've created `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/kbd.hwdb` with the mapping `KEYBOARD_KEY_70048=grave` and **this works when Gnome is set up with an american keyboard layout**. When I change to norwegian, this does **not** work, and instead I get a bar, `|` when pressing <kbd>Pause|Break</kbd>.

Does anyone know why this does not work with a norwegian layout? I've followed the instructions [here](https://www.foell.org/justin/remapping-keyboard-keys-in-ubuntu-with-udev-evdev/).

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit**: After doing this and running `evtest` the key reported *is* a  `KEY_GRAVE`, but it outputs a bar `|`. Very confusing!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having the same problem;

The solution was to use keyd (https://github.com/rvaiya/keyd) and create a macro that basically mimics the keystrokes necessary to produce the wanted symbol.

In the case of mapping the pause key to the grave key/symbol, I had to put the following in keyds config file (grave is a dead key, so need some fuzz):

pause = macro(S-= space space backspace)